# How to do a reverse moving average ( in pandas, rolling().mean ) operation on predicted values?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a df like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.rand(200,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'y']

df['y_roll'] = df['y'].rolling(10).mean()
df['y_roll_predicted'] = df['y_roll'].apply(lambda x: x + np.random.rand()/20)
```

In above code, I created a random pandas `df`. Then used `rolling(10).mean()` to perform a `moving average` on`df['y']` and saved it as `df['y_roll']`.

plot of `df['y']` is as follows:
[image: plot of y]

Because my model was not able to predict sharp edges of `df['y']`, I decided to do a rolling.mean() operation on it and try to predict the rolled data, `df['y_roll']`. Now my model is able to predict `df['y_roll']` and its name is: `df['y_roll_predicted']`.

How can I do a reverse of rolling operation on this predicted column, so that I can compare it with `df['y']` values?

plot of `df['y_roll_predicted']` vs `df['y_roll']` is as follows:
 [image]

Comment: This is not on stackoverflow, but there is a pretty good answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/extract-data-points-from-moving-average/68002#68002) that includes a python/numpy solution

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/extract-data-points-from-moving-average/68002#68002

Comment: I think that the answer I propose is different, more focus on the software implementation that on the mathematical way of understanding it.

Answer (score 5):

This is very related with this question [cumsum with shift of n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155524/python-pandas-cumsum-with-shift-of-n) I asked.

With this function `cumsum_shif(n)` (the question provides an implementation using for loops called **cumsum_shift**) you can reverse the moving average up to constant that depends on the initial values **without the need of inverting a matrix that has to have as many columns as the the size of the original serie**.

Let's call the moving average `y_roll = df.loc[,"y_roll"]` and `y_estimated` the reverse up to a constant. Assuming the size of the windows is 10 `win_size = 10` then if you multiply by 10 the `diff`'ed of the rolling mean and then `cumumsum(shift=10)` it you obtain the original serie up to the intial values.
The code:

```
def cumsum_shift(s, shift = 1, init_values = [0]):
    s_cumsum = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(s)))
    for i in range(shift):
        s_cumsum.iloc[i] = init_values[i]
    for i in range(shift,len(s)):
        s_cumsum.iloc[i] = s_cumsum.iloc[i-shift] + s.iloc[i]
    return s_cumsum

win_size = 10
s_diffed = win_size * df['y_roll'].diff()
df['y_unrolled'] = cumsum_shift(s=s_diffed, shift = win_size, init_values= df['y'].values[:win_size])
```

This code recovers exactly `y` from `y_roll` because you have the initial values.

You can see it plotting it (in my case with plotly) that `y` and `y_unrolled` are exactly the same (just the red one).
[image]

Now doing the same thing to `y_roll_predicted` to obtain `y_predicted_unrolled`.

Code:

```
win_size = 10
s_diffed = win_size * df['y_roll_predicted'].diff()
df['y_predicted_unrolled'] = cumsum_shift(s=s_diffed, shift = win_size, init_values= df['y'].values[:win_size])
```

In this case the result are not exactly the same, notice how the *initial values* are from `y` and then `y_roll_predicted` incorporate noise to `y_roll` so the "unrolling" cannot recover exactly the original one.

Here a plot zoomed in in a smaller range to see it better:
[image]