# Python Pandas cumsum with shift of n

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know if there is an efficient way (avoiding for loops) of doing a `serie.cumsum()` but with a **shift of n**.

The same way you can see `serie.cumsum()` like the inverse of `serie.diff(1)` I am looking for an inverse of `diff(n)` (I know that for a proper inverse you need the initial values but for simplicity I ignore them here) that could be called `cumsum_shift`

More explicitly implementing it with a **for loop** (which I would like to avoid):

```py
def cumsum_shift(s, shift = 1, init_values = [0]):
    s_cumsum = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(s)))
    for i in range(shift):
        s_cumsum.iloc[i] = init_values[i]
    for i in range(shift,len(s)):
        s_cumsum.iloc[i] = s_cumsum.iloc[i-shift] + s.iloc[i]
    return s_cumsum
```

This code with `shift = 1` is exactly the same that the `s.cumsum()` pandas method does but of course the **pandas method do it in C code** (I guess) so it is much faster (of course you should always use the `s.cumsum()` pandas method and not implement it yourself with a for loop).

My question then is
**What would be the way of doing `cumsum_shift` avoiding a for loop with pandas methods?**

### Edit 1

Adding an example of input and output

If you call it with:

```py
s = pd.Series([1,10,100,2,20,200,5,50,500])
s.diff(3)
out[26] 0      NaN
        1      NaN
        2      NaN
        3      1.0
        4     10.0
        5    100.0
        6      3.0
        7     30.0
        8    300.0
        dtype: float64
```

With this input, the ouput of `cumsum_shift(s.diff(3), shift = 3, init_values = [1,2,3])` is again the original series `s`. Notice the shift of 3, this with just `cumsum()` e.g `s.diff(3).cumsum()` would not recover the original `s`:

```
cumsum_shift(s.diff(3), shift = 3, init_values= [1,10,100])
out[27]
0      1.0
1     10.0
2    100.0
3      2.0
4     20.0
5    200.0
6      5.0
7     50.0
8    500.0
dtype: float64
```

But let me emphasize that the initial values is not a big deal, a constant difference is not a problem. I would like to know **how to perform a cumsum of shifted differenced serie without having to use a for loop**

The same way that if you do a `diff()` and then a `cumsum()` you get back the orginal one up to the initial value:

```
s = pd.Series([1,10,100,2,20,200,5,50,500])
s.diff().cumsum()
out[28]
0      NaN
1      9.0
2     99.0
3      1.0
4     19.0
5    199.0
6      4.0
7     49.0
8    499.0
dtype: float64
```

I would like to know if there some clever way of doing something like `s.diff(n).cumsum(n)` that returned something correct up to some constant initial values.

**EDIT 2 - Reverse a Moving Average**

Thinking of an application of the "shifted cumsum" I found this [other question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456267/how-to-do-a-reverse-moving-average-in-pandas-rolling-mean-operation-on-pr/64158928#64158928) of how to **reverse a moving average** that I have answered using my `cumsum_shift` function and I think it clarifies more what I am asking here

Comment: Can you please share a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Ok Mayank,let me edit the question but as a summary the idea is to obtain the inverse of a diff(periods = n)

Comment: I'm confused by all your examples but I see no clear request... perhaps start over and write a) sample data, b) expected output, and c) brief explanation of computation logic

Comment: Maybe tring to give too much information I have make it more confuse, the big summary is I want to know if there is a compact way of inverting `diff(preiods=n)` for any n the same way as cumsum() inverts `diff(periods =1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas method [rolling.sum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) among with sum:

```
s.rolling(shift).sum()
```

However you may want to fill the NaN values until the shift with the original df.

Comment: oh, i just saw your edited post. So if i got correctly you are wondering if there is a compact function which first does diff() and then cumsum()?

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. This is adding windows of size shift/n, and I am referring to recover from a `diff(n)`,I have test it and it is not working